# How to implement search after data fetch with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, function, api, react-hooks, jsx

I have done a fetch from an API and I want to add a search component so I can be able to search a single user from the data fetched. And I need some help to be able to do it properly. Thanks for your help and I hope that I have been understandable. Here below you can see what I have done:

**DataFethed.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Search from "./Search";

function DataFethed() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benna100/5fd674171ea528d7cd1d504e9bb0ca6f/raw"
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        setUsers(res.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const searchHandler = value => {
    setSearchValue(value);
  };

  let updateUsers = users.filter(item => {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h5>Shift OverViewShift</h5>
      <Search searchHandler={searchHandler} />
      {updateUsers.map((shifts, index) => (
        <DataFethed key={index} props={shifts} />
      ))}
      <ul>
        {users.map(user => (
          <ol key={user.name}>
            <br />
            {user.name} <br />
            {user.start} <br />
            {user.end}
          </ol>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataFetched;
```

**Search.js:**

```
import React from "react";

const Search = ({ searchHandler }) => {
  const handleSearchInputChange = e => {
    searchHandler(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form className="search">
      <input
        onChange={handleSearchInputChange}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search Name..."
      />
      <i className="fas fa-search" type="submit" value="SEARCH"></i>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Comment: Exactly, what is the problem? By looking at your code, it should work. What do you mean with *doing it properly*?

Comment: Thanks Jolly, the problem is when I run it the browser bug and the search field is rendering several time and can not be used.

Comment: Again, in the code you wrote there is no error. I've tried to use your code in CodeSandBox and it works: I've only changed the line in which you render `<ShiftManager>`. Could you provide also the code for that component?

Comment: shiftManager was the name of the function that I changed to DataFetched, maybe that could be the problem. Can you tell me How did you change <ShiftManager> so I can try my side?

Comment: Well, if you try to import a component that no longer exists, you surely have an issue. Then, suppose you fix that: you wanted to render a `DataFetched` inside a `DataFetched`?

Comment: The result that I want to get it is, when I write the name of one user in the search input I should see only that name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the comments we exchanged, you just need a conditional rendering. Inside `DataFetched`, you should write this `return` statement:

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h5>Shift OverViewShift</h5>
    <Search searchHandler={searchHandler} />
    <ul>
      {(searchValue === '' ? users : updateUsers).map(user => (
        <ol key={user.name}>
          <br />
          {user.name} <br />
          {user.start} <br />
          {user.end}
        </ol>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Basically, now, when `searchValue` is **NOT** empty (meaning you are searching), you use `updateUsers` to render the user. Instead, when `searchValue` is empty, you render **ALL** the user by using `users`.
Moreover, since you have the same structure in both `users` and `updateUsers`, you can use the same `map()` function: notice that the ternary operator only specifies if using `users` or `updateUsers`.